# SVM prediction of images OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, svm

I'm able to train the system but when I try to predict, Bad argument exception is raised.

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The sample is not a valid vector) in cvPreparePredictData, file ........\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 1099
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ........\opencv\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:1099: error: (-5) The sample is not a valid vector in function cvPreparePredictData
]

This is my code:

```
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat classes = new Mat();
        Mat trainingData = new Mat();
        Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
        Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();
        CvSVM clasificador;
        String path="C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\Color_Happy_jpg";
       for (File file : new File(path).listFiles()) {
            Mat img=new Mat();   
            Mat con = Highgui.imread(path+"\\"+file.getName(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            con.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);

                img.reshape(1, 1);
                trainingImages.push_back(img);
               trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.ones(new Size(1, 75), CvType.CV_32FC1));

            }
        System.out.println("divide");
        path="C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\Color_Sad_jpg";
          for (File file : new File(path).listFiles()) {
                Mat img=new Mat();
                Mat m=new Mat(new Size(640,480),CvType.CV_32FC1);
                Mat con = Highgui.imread(file.getAbsolutePath(),Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

                con.convertTo(img, CvType.CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
                img.reshape(1, 1);
                trainingImages.push_back(img);

                trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.zeros(new Size(1, 75), CvType.CV_32FC1));

              }

            trainingLabels.copyTo(classes);
            CvSVMParams params = new CvSVMParams();
            params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.LINEAR);
            CvType.typeToString(trainingImages.type());
            CvSVM svm=new CvSVM();



            clasificador = new CvSVM(trainingImages,classes, new Mat(), new Mat(), params);

            clasificador.save("C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\svm.xml");
            Mat out=new Mat();

            clasificador.load("C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\svm.xml");
            Mat sample=Highgui.imread("C:\\java workspace\\ora\\images\\Color_Sad_jpg\\EMBfemale20-2happy.jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

           sample.convertTo(out, CvType.CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);               
            out.reshape(1, 75);
            System.out.println(clasificador.predict(out));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.

your trainLabels are still wrong.

you need a float mat with numrows==numimages and 1 col. so, 1 label per image.

so your sad faces should have :

```
trainingLabels.push_back(-1.0);
```

and your happy ones should have :

```
trainingLabels.push_back(1.0);
```

### 2.

the sample for the prediction has to be processed in the same way as for the training.

```
sample.convertTo(out, CvType.CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);               
out.reshape(1, 1);
```